# SSD fstrim on CentOS 6.x with software raid5

Tags: centos6, ssd, ext4, md, trim

I have some CentOS 6.x servers. They have `software raid1` and `fstrim` works well there.

On one of the servers, I decided to do `software raid5` and `ext4`. I can mount it with `discard` and there is no error message.

However if I decide to run `fstrim`, I get this:

```
[root@server ~]#  fstrim /        <- (raid1 works well)
[root@server ~]#  fstrim /SSD     <- (raid5 does not work)
fstrim: /SSD: FITRIM ioctl failed: Operation not supported
[root@server ~]# uname -a
Linux server 2.6.32-573.12.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Dec 15 21:19:08 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The disk supports trim and there is raid1 made with same disks.

Is this because RedHat did not backported something into the kernel or I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mdraid support for discard on RAID 5 wasn't available in the 2.6 kernel series; it was [added in the 3.7 kernel](http://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_3.7#head-2fd9b183a4623d96e69ed24f88e0eb83217fa8df). I'm not aware of Red Hat backporting this functionality.

Once you get a kernel with this functionality, [you may find that it is disabled](http://www.spinics.net/lists/raid/msg49619.html), because some (older) SSDs don't actually implement TRIM properly. In this case, you need to set the kernel module option `raid456.devices_handle_discard_safely=Y` and then **test thoroughly** before putting the system into production.

Comment: very helpful. I thought 2.6 do not support trim for md at all